# Data Update - SQL syntax Error

Tags: php, mysql

I can not change data in the table..

```
    UPDATE users
    SET  mem_expire = 2111-10-10 00:00:00
    WHERE  mem_expire = 0000-00-00 00:00:00;
```

**MySql Error:**

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '00:00:00 WHERE mem_expire = 0000-00-00 00:00:00' at line 2

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: What data type is mem_expire?

Comment: Quote the new date `mem_expire = '2111-10-10 00:00:00'` and the old one.  `WHERE  mem_expire = '0000-00-00 00:00:00';

Comment: [STR_TO_DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) is the best means, providing flexibility for whatever date format you want to use rather than the standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Date string literals have to be surrounded by Quotes like so:

```
 UPDATE users
 SET  mem_expire = '2111-10-10 00:00:00'
 WHERE  mem_expire = '0000-00-00 00:00:00';
```

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
UPDATE users 
SET  mem_expire = '2111-10-10 00:00:00' 
WHERE  mem_expire = '0000-00-00 00:00:00';
```

You need to add ' (plings)

Comment: Romo is right, since this is a string/value you're working with, you want to be sure to wrap it with quotes so MySQL doesn't try to treat `0000-00-00 00:00:00` as a MySQL keyword, but a string.